# ExpressJs prevent multer from reassigns a new req.body

Tags: node.js, express, multer

When using Multer, it **reassigns** a new req.body, causing other values in req.body (even if manually added through a middleware, not as part of the request body) to be deleted.

In this example, I am using AuthMiddleware, which checks if the token is valid and assigns a **user** property to **req.body** so that I can later retrieve the current authenticated user with **req.body.user**. However, when using Multer, this doesn't work.

multer config and routes

```
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
        cb(null, `user-${Date.now()}-${randomNumber}.${ext}`);
    },
});

const multerFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype.startsWith('image')) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(new AppError('Not an image! Please upload only images.'), false);
    }
};

const multerConfig = multer({ storage: multerStorage, fileFilter: multerFilter });

AuthRoutes.post('/me/update-photo', AuthMiddleware, multerConfig.array('photo', 1), updatePhoto);
```

AuthMiddleware.js

```
const AuthMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    let authorization = req.headers.authorization;
    //... some logic the get token and check it
    
    req.body.user = user; //<-- add user to body , so I can later use req.body.user to get the current auth user

    next();
};
```

controller function

```
exports.updatePhoto = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    console.log(req.body);
    // log : [Object: null prototype] {}

};
```

If I send some fields as form-data, I can certainly g tethem, but I don't want that. I want multer to only handle file uploads without changing req.body.user, or if there is a better approach  ?

Comment: add it to `req` instead: `req.user = user;`

Comment: yes this is what i did and it's working, but the problem is if have others middleware  that can manipulate and change the req.body

Comment: yes, it doesn't preserve javascript object properties, it seems it creates fresh object: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js#L28, and then uses only fields that are parsed with busboy depending on the request type: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js#L93, If you really want it to be part of the body, then you could store it in `req.user`, and then in some multer method/other middleware reassign it to body: `req.body.user = req.user`...